# Postgresql 9.6 autovacuum blocks all update operations

Tags: postgresql, performance, locking, postgresql-9.6, autovacuum

I have a table with following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.json_stream_packet_filter
(
  stream_packet_id bigint NOT NULL,
  filter_data jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT json_stream_packet_filter_pkey PRIMARY KEY (stream_packet_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE,
  autovacuum_enabled=true,
  autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=5000,
  toast.autovacuum_vacuum_threshold=5000
);

CREATE INDEX call_started_index
  ON public.json_stream_packet_filter
  USING btree
  (to_text((filter_data -> 'call'::text) ->> 'started_at'::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX json_stream_packet_filter_filter_data_idx
  ON public.json_stream_packet_filter
  USING gin
  (filter_data jsonb_path_ops);
```

It absorbs a lot of updates, and spans with indices to about 6Gb, so every autovacuum takes about two hours. I thought that autovacuum doesn't block either select's, insert or updates, but in fact it is. I have a lot of updates waiting for autovacuum process with page Lock. I look into pg_locks by autovacuums pid and i saw this:

```
select locktype, mode, relation::regclass from pg_locks
where pid = 3855

relation    RowExclusiveLock    json_stream_packet_filter_filter_data_idx
relation    RowExclusiveLock    call_started_index
relation    RowExclusiveLock    json_stream_packet_filter_pkey
virtualxid  ExclusiveLock   
relation    ShareUpdateExclusiveLock    json_stream_packet_filter
```

so my question is: how i could overcome it? How to tell autovacuum not to lock indice pages, or lock it not for so long time ?

Comment: First enable [`log_autovacuum_min_duration`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) to get a sense of what's going on.

Comment: i already know that autovacuum takes really long, an hour or an hour and a half. What is the help of `log_autovacuum_min_duration` ?

Comment: Your query of pg_locks does not show any page locks being held.  What are the locks the blocked processes are blocking on?

Comment: there is a lot of queries that waiting on page lock, i just didnt paste their result from pg_stat_activity or from pg_locks. Believe me, there is a LOT of queries waiting by 30 min and above. And it's just an update of single row wainting so much. Astonishing.

Comment: Do those `autovacuum` processes perform an anti-wraparound vacuum?

Comment: Nope, that is usual autovacuum, not freeze, not anti-wraparound, not analyze